# HTML Arabic text

Tags: html, fonts, character-encoding, arabic

I have some Arabic text that needs to be displayed in my php file - but the characters are not recognized.

How do I create a document with Arabic support?

Comment: "the characters are not recognized" - what does that mean? A proper browser will happily display an HTML page, if it's UTF-8 encoded and you tell the browser so. UTF-8 can encode all Unicode characters, including Arabic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem will be here that your browser is not capable due to a necessary font or character table which is not being used.
Have [a look at this testpage i](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arabic.html)n order to find out if your browser is capable of displaying arabic characters with its actual setting.

[This page](http://www.menalib.de/vlib/html/docs/arabwww_en.html) covers the necessary browser settings to display arabic characters.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that you're using UTF-8 charset all the way. UTF-8 supports all characters the world is aware of. Save the PHP file as UTF-8. Set the DB table charset to UTF-8. Set the DB connection charset to UTF-8. Set the HTTP response header charset to UTF-8. See also [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet).

Comment: That’s a bit idealistic. While it is indeed true that any UTF encoding (Unicode Transform Function, including UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32) supports all possible Unicode code points, Unicode does not itself “support all characters that the world is aware of.” The world is a very big place, and its imagination is unbounded. That said, Unicode does indeed support a heck of a lot of them, many — perhaps even most — of which few people have ever heard of, with more constantly being added. If they were all already there, there’d be no need to keeping adding more. :)