# jquery load function loads wrong arabic text

Tags: jquery, get, load, arabic

I am using load function to load the html content of DIV. the content contains arabic characters, after loading the arabic characters appears as ?????????, I tried also $.get function the same problem. If I open the html directlly from the browser the arabic apperas currectlly. Can any one help how to solve this problem

Comment: can you give us an example for your html content and div code , i think you can solve it by encoding conf please provide code

Comment: function loadSearchPanels(url) {
 $("#panel").load(url);
}

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<div>
 <div color=green>ÇáãäØÞÉ:<BR><input type=text value="" id=zone><a href="#"><img width=14 height=14 src=zoom-in.png onclick=zoomToZone()></a><BR></div>
 <div color=green>المنطقة:<BR><input type=text value="" id=category></div>

Comment: What encoding does the page you're loading from use?

Answer (score 0):

To show arabic text you need to do some encoding and change browser settings. You can get help from following links:

[How can I view Arabic/Persian numbers in a HTML page with strict doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635939/how-can-i-view-arabic-persian-numbers-in-a-html-page-with-strict-doctype)

http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/

[HTML Arabic text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724223/html-arabic-text)

http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arabic.html

You can try this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir just add the encoding format to your html content

```
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: then try to add the encoding in the response http header

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem just use this after database connection:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');       // object oriented style 
<br/>
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4');  // procedural style
```

Regards