# how i can input arabic character to this code?

Tags: javascript, regex, tags, arabic

how i can input arabic character to this code , i have tags in my site but i cant tags(arabic) ?

```
$('#tags').on('tokenfield:createdtoken', function (e) {
        var re = /^[a-z0-9][\w\s\ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜäëïöüçÇßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð\-]+$/i
        var valid = re.test(e.attrs.value)
        if (!valid) {
          $(e.relatedTarget).addClass('invalid').remove()
        }
      }).tokenfield({
        limit: 10,
        beautify: false
        });
```

please help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Arabic text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724223/html-arabic-text)

Comment: @user573 test a short tag "مرة"

Answer (score 0):

Add the list of Arabic alphabet to your regex:

```
> var re = /^[a-z0-9األآإـتنمكطدجحخهعغفقثصضشسيبئءؤرىةوزظذ][\w\sألآإـتنمكطدجحخهعغفقثصضشسيبئءؤرىةوزظذا\ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜäëïöüçÇßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð\-]+$/i

> "العربية".match(re)
[ 'العربية',
  index: 0,
  input: 'العربية' ]

> "english mixed with العربية".match(re)
[ 'english mixed with العربية',
  index: 0,
  input: 'english mixed with العربية' ]
```